# PHP imap_search filter X-priority header

Tags: php, imap, email-headers

Currently I'm writing a script to move emails from a folder to a different folder. All mails containing the `X-Priority: 3` header should be moved.

Part of source of the mail:

```
Date: DATE
To: NAME <EMAIL>
From: "NAME" <EMAIL>
Subject: SUBJECT
Message-ID: <SOMEID@EMAIL>
X-Priority: 3
```

Code I'm using:

```
$imapStream = imap_open('{HOST}Sent', 'EMAIL', 'PASSWORD');
$emailIds = imap_search($imapStream, 'ALL');
rsort($emailIds);

foreach ($emailIds as $emailId) {
    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($imapStream, $emailId, 0);
    $message = imap_fetchtext($imapStream, $emailId, 2);

    var_dump($overview); // <-- Doesn't contain X-Priority
    die;
}
```

Now, I need to filter all emails that has the `X-Priority` header set. I first thought I could maybe check the `imap_fetch_overview`, `imap_fetchtext` or `imap_fetchbody` but none contain the `X-Priority`. However, the `X-Priority` isn't a valid `imap_search` criteria.

How can I filter the mailbox and get only the emails with the `X-Priority` header?

Comment: Get the headers?

Comment: If your server follows the speech, you can also search headers for arbitrary criteria using the `HEADER` search criteria.  Note: it is not rare for servers to not have this support.

Comment: Though PHP gives an error with `imap_search` `HEADER`. But I found the solution already (it seems like it).

Comment: *Autocorrect:  "If your server follows the spec"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I should've looked better before posting but I'll post my findings anyways:

I found out I could get the headers with `imap_fetchheader`, which also contains the `X-Priority` header (duh...)

So the code to retrieve it would be:

```
$headers = explode("\n", imap_fetchheader($imapStream, $emailId, 0));
```

In case of filtering, I could use `TEXT` as criteria to filter emails with a certain `X-Priority`, like this:

```
$emailIds = imap_search($imapStream, 'TEXT "X-Priority: 3"');
```

This seems to get all emails containing the `X-Priority` header only.